# "Deceased" flag set to "no" by default in standard reports

Tags: reports, default-settings

Why is the "Deceased" flag set to "no" by default in standard reports ? This causes waste of time in understanding why the search results are not full. All other flags are set to "any".
Is it possible to change this default value in the reports templates?
Thank you

Comment: I guess the thinking is that most of the time, most of us want to know about live contacts so setting that as the default saves time overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save an instance of the report that has your preferred settings and then have it appear in the menu or on the dashboard.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/reporting/set-up/#define-report-settings

Briefly, set your settings, refresh the report, look at the Access tab for any additional settings like menu entry, and then choose Create Report from the actions dropdown.